# How to remove circular dependency in turn based game?

Tags: java, oop

I'm currently working on the design for a Java game, and I have come across an issue with circular dependency between classes. Here is a (simplified) example of my current problem:

```
class Game
class Player
class Ability
```

Games have Players which in turn have Abilities (e.g. a spell or attack). An Ability has a method like:

```
public void perform(Player source, Game game);
```

The issue is that Ability requires knowledge of the Game (and Player/game object), in order to perform its actions. Are there any ways to solve this?

---

Update: I appreciate the responses. I see now that Abilities shouldn't really be owned by Players.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to link Players and Abilities then.  For example, take a game like Pokemon where each creature has abilities it can use.  Or take a collectible card game, where each card can have abilities that affect any part of the game.  There has to be some way to determine which Players (or any ability-using object) can use which Abilities, even if the Abilities are not directly owned by the Players.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are circular class dependencies within the same package (assuming they are in the same pacakge) a problem? IMO, when I think of circular dependencies, I tend to think at the package level, not the class level. Package circular dependencies are more problematic because it makes the code more difficult to refactor. Classes in the same package are likely going to be related, and some tight coupling is sometime unavoidable.

In your particular case, @Woot4Moo has pointed out some possible design changes, but I don't think it's a general rule of thumb that circular dependencies between classes within the same package are so bad.

Comment: Agree with those insights.

Answer (score 3):

Your Ability class doesn't need to know it's in a Game.  You need an Engine or Environment class that represents the rules and make up of the Game.  This will enable you to drop premade players into infinitely many game engines.  For instance you can have a LowGravityEngine and a QuantumEngine.  These engines would allow a better design in terms of separating your model(Player) from the controller (Engine or Game).

If you don't want Engines refactor your Game to take Player objects instead of Ability taking a Game.  It doesn't make sense.  For instance in Monopoly the dog piece doesn't know how to buy properties.

Answer (score 0):

One way to design this would be to implement a parent-children dependency.

For instance, in your `Player` fields:

```
private Game parent;
```

Then, say, in your `Player` constructor:

```
public Player(Game parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}
```

And of course, a public method such as:

```
public final Game getParent() {
    return parent;
}
```

Then you could call `perform` with only the `Player` instance as argument, and query the `Game` instance fields within the body of the method.

In case your `Game` classes only provide static data (like "rules"), you could also pass as `Class` as argument instead of a `Game` instance.

However, this is one solution out of an infinite number.

Woot4Moo's solution makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

If the `perform` function in `Ability` needs knowledge of the `Player`, you're in effect using the [strategy design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), since you can choose from any of a number of abilities based on parameters you mass to the `perform` function (these parameters being, in this case, the `Player` itself and the `Game`).

Think of it this way. A `Player` doesn't *own* an ability, it instead *uses* one, and it's up to the perform function to select the right one(s) to use based on the parameters that a `Player` passes to it. You're in effect *plugging in* an ability to a `Player`, except you don't do it be specifying one of many abilities to use, but instead by letting the `perform` function choose the right action for you. Crucially, your `Player` doesn't own this action itself. There isn't, thus, any circular dependency at all, if I understand your question correctly.